# Проблема с Retrofit в android 5.1

Tags: android, retrofit

Обычно, когда нет интернета, в onFailure приходит ошибка "Unable to resolve host "hostname.com": No address associated with hostname". В Android 5.1 при отсутствии интернета приходит ошибка timeout, более того, при возобновлении интернета ошибка не пропадает и ни один запрос не проходит удачно - везде timeout. Проверял на двух эмуляторах с версией 5.1. На эмуляторах с другими версиями а так же на моем смартфоне с версией 5.0.2 все работает нормально. Почему так происходит?